# Single executable for both windows and linux?

Tags: linux, windows

Is it possible to have single standalone executable to be able to run on both linux and windows? It doesn't have to be from one binary code. I have no problem compiling linux version with gcc, windows one with mingw and then "merging" them. Is something like this possible?

I guess question is if it's possible to write both PE and ELF into one file. Or if there is some basic scripting thing both linux and windows understand.

Comment: Does it have to be a compiled executable containing machine code? You can write portable programs in Java, Python, etc.

Comment: well I guess my main point is that I want single file to download from internet. so in the case of interpreted languagues, I would need to pack both linux and windows interpret into it

Comment: In practice, people are so used to downloading the specific installer for their operating system, that you may find having a single cross-platform installer causes more confusion than it avoids. :-)

Comment: Maybe it's better to hybrid `cmd` and `bash`. The first line `#!/bin/bash` would be simply printing a error message in cmd.

Answer (score -1):

From a compilation (C, C++, etc.) standpoint, no there isn't. There are always interpreted(scripting) languages like Python and Ruby that can be run on all platforms. Then there's Java, which can be run everywhere ([theoretically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24349726/if-its-write-once-run-anywhere-why-do-so-many-java-programs-tell-me-to-pick)). Also, bash scripts and I think linux executables *can* be mostly run by using cygwin or MinGW on windows, but there is no native way with shell scripting.